# Projection error using spring entity

Tags: java, spring

So I'm making a projection for an entity called CodeCenterApplications. See the entity below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CODE_CENTER_APPLICATIONS")
public class CodeCenterApplication {

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT")
    protected Integer id;
    protected String name;
    protected String version;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    protected Date insertionDate;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "APPROVALS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATION_ID", columnDefinition = "BIGINT")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "API_ID")})
    private List<API> apis;

    public CodeCenterApplication() {
    }

    public CodeCenterApplication(Integer id, String name, String version) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }


    public CodeCenterApplication(Integer id, String name, String version, Date insertionDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
        this.insertionDate = insertionDate;
    }

    public List<API> getApis() {
        return apis;
    }

    public void setApis(List<API> apis) {
        this.apis = apis;
    }

    /**
     * Can be used if you wish to generate a table with the appropriate headers.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    public String[] getColumnNames() {
        String[] header = {"NAME", "VERSION", "INSERTION_DATE"};
        return header;
    }

    /**
     * A giant 'getter' for all all attributes save for id.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    public String[] getAttributeList() {
        String insertionDateString = "2016-01-01"; //insertionDate.toString();
        String[] attributeList = {name, version, insertionDateString};
        return attributeList;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.name = Name;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Date getInsertionDate() {
        return insertionDate;
    }

    public void setInsertionDate(Date insertionDate) {
        this.insertionDate = insertionDate;
    }
}
```

The projection is as follows, as you can see I only want the name

```
public interface NameOnly {

    String getName();
}
```

Finally, here is the method in the repository that uses it

```
/**
 * The following strings are used in creating queries.
 */
String fuzzySchema = "\"FROODES2\"";
String fuzzyTable = "\"APPLICATIONS\"";
String fuzzyColumns = "\"NAME\"";
String fuzzySearchInput = ":name";

 String fuzzyGroupSearchString = "SELECT " + fuzzyColumns + " FROM " + fuzzySchema + "." + fuzzyTable
            + " WHERE CONTAINS((" + fuzzyColumns + "), " + fuzzySearchInput + ", FUZZY(0.75)) GROUP BY " +
            fuzzyColumns + ", SCORE()" + " ORDER BY " + "SCORE() " + "DESC " + "LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset";


    @Query(value = fuzzyGroupSearchString, nativeQuery = true)
    List<NameOnly> findByNameGrouped(@Param("name") String name, @Param("offset") int offset, @Param("limit") int
            limit);
```

However, when I try to call this repository method, I get the following error

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Could not find field for property during fallback access! (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->$Proxy136["name"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid property 'name' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Could not find field for property during fallback access! (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->$Proxy136["name"])
```

I notice its not detecting that getName() is supposed to be referring to the entity, but instead it thinks it's trying to get the attribute of a String.

Also, this is my first question, so critique is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is a ORM framework which maps a Java Object (Entity Object) to a relational daatabase, you did NOT map all your properties (name, version , etc..) of `CodeCenterApplication` to the database table.

As you are using annotations, you need to use `@Column` to map the property to the database table column like below:

```
@Column(name="YOUR_TABLE_COLUMN")

protected String name;

//other properties also need to be mapped including insertionDate
```

You can look at [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/)